# How is the Win32 API used in C++ to minimize a window to the system tray?

Tags: c++, winapi, minimize

Pretty much a self-explanatory title. I'm writing an application in C++ with the Win32 API, and I'd like to know how to minimize to the system tray. I can find all kinds of articles online about minimizing to the system tray in C#, Python, even Visual Basic, I think, but for the life of me I can not find a single article on how to minimize something to the system tray in C++.

Any and all help or even redirection would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Question answered. Once I knew about the Shell_NotifyIcon function, I was easily able to find [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/StealthDialog.aspx) which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: When you say minimize to the tray, do you mean just having a tray icon or do you want the minimize animation for your window to minimize down to your tray icon and not the taskbar button?

Comment: @Anders: I hadn't actually thought about the animation, but that would be pretty sweet. Any ideas on that?

Comment: SetWindowPlacement can set the minimize target, you just need to find the tray rectangle, Shell_NotifyIconGetRect does that on Win7, <=Vista you need to use FindWindow and undocumented class names

Comment: There is a missing res/dlg.manifest on the CodeProject zip file.
I know this is an old thread, but can anyone provide it or point what to add/delete/change? Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need is the [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx) function. You ought to be able to work it out from MSDN, but if you need more help I'm sure there are a million places on the web that give samples. Now that you know the name of the API, web search will fill in the gaps.