# System Tray Icon in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray

I got a basic window made from C++. What I need to do is whenever I click the Minimize button the window will be placed in the System Tray and whenever I double click on the Icon it will restore...

Comment: Some suggestions. 1) Tag it with the platform you're targeting both OS (Windows I guess, but I don't *know* ) and the API system you're using 2) Show us what you *do* have and explain what your *don't* know.

Comment: I use Window XP and WinAPI.. I want to know how could I put my program  to system tray whenever I minimize it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do is the Win32 API used in C++ to minimize a window to the system tray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844445/how-do-is-the-win32-api-used-in-c-to-minimize-a-window-to-the-system-tray)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

check msdn about 
a struct: NOTIFYICONDATA 
and a function:

BOOL Shell_NotifyIcon( DWORD dwMessage,PNOTIFYICONDATA lpdata);

---

and also a [demo](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/systemtray.aspx) here.

Hope you can understand:)

Comment: what if I want to show/hide systems icon like network/volume/microphone?

Answer (score 20):

You will need to use [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159(VS.85).aspx) to interact with the notification area (system tray).

Comment: how could I used Shell_NotifyIcon?

Comment: what if I want to show/hide systems icon like network/volume/microphone?

Comment: @j.doe sounds like you should just ask this as a question.