# Event on Application Minimized in C++ Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, minimize

Is there a signal or event in the Windows Desktop API that can tell me if my application is in a minimized state? I looked through msdn documentation and have only found minimize events that call as the application is minimizing, not when the application is already done the minimize and in a final minimized state.

I need to set another operation off ( a screen capture) when I know the window that I set is minimized and out of the way of the screen capture. I use the WM_SIZE message to check the window is minimized, then start the screen capture. My problem is that I can still see the application window closing when the screen capture is taken (i.e. the minimization animation done by most application windows), even though I got a SIZE_MINIMIZED message through a ProcessWindowMessage callback. I need something to tell me that the application is fully minimized, and not in the way of the screen capture I am taking of the entire desktop.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question title asks for an "event", your question also asks for checking the state.  It isn't very clear what you are asking.

Comment: It looks like there's one answer for each way of reading it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`IsIconic()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); if your window is minimized that API will return non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  It will be sent after the window's size has changed.   If you window was minimised the `wParam` variable should be equal to `SIZE_MINIMIZED`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution mentioned here:
[How could I detect when my application is minimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966194/how-could-i-detect-when-my-application-is-minimized)

~snip:

```
switch (message)
{
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    if ((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MINIMIZE)
    {
        // shrink the application to the notification area
        // ...

        return 0;
    }
    break;
}
```

Or try the GetWindowPlacement function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx

~snip

> Retrieves the show state and the restored, minimized, and maximized positions of the specified window.