# How to make a taskbar (system tray) application in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, taskbar, system-tray, visual-c++-2008

The only way I know to launch a windows application is through `CreateWindow`. Unfortunately, there is not a [window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600.aspx) for a taskbar application, and I was wondering how to make a one. I did find [this explanation](http://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/) in C#, but I am looking for a solution able to be compiled with VC++ 2008. Any solutions?

Comment: Taskbar and tray are two different things. And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964630/system-tray-icon-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is `Shell_NotifyIcon` (as other users suggested).

In a standard scenario your application should have at least one window (at least to receive system tray notification messages). Possibly hidden. On right-click on your tray icon it's a good tone to display a sort of a popoup menu.

I think you may look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7469/Quick-code-page-converter). This simple program demonstrates how to use the system tray in a very minimalistic way.