# Instance in VC++ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, background

Am working on VC++ application

Its a background application that runs on background even on PC restart

Am trying to open the application as say - some antivirus like mcafee, which runs on background but if we click on the exe icon it comes up front of the screen

```
                WinExec("application.exe", SW_SHOW);
                exit(1);
```

Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: WinExec("application.exe", SW_SHOW);
 exit(1);

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an application that runs in the system tray? Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964630/system-tray-icon-in-c

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the same idea. But it should not run in system tray. It should run as process in background. And if we click the exe from program files it should show the UI screen

Comment: If that application is not supposed to run in background, it is unlikely you'll be able to run it that way. You can change SW_SHOW to SW_HIDE or SW_MINIMIZE though.

Comment: Are you writing code targeting 16-bit Windows? The `WinExec` function became obsolete when Windows 95 was released, nearly 20 years ago. You should be using `CreateProcess` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your application is a good candidate for a Windows Service.  A Service runs in the background with no GUI, starts when Windows starts, can re-start automatically if it fails, etc.  For a GUI, you would write a separate application which would attach to the Service via some type of inter-process-communication for the purposes of configuration/control.